# how to find changed files in a subset of a sourcetree

Tags: git, magento, diff

I have a git repo of a magento installation. into this repo has been installed an extension some time ago. this extension has been modified (or some files thereof). I now want to find out which files (of the extension files only!) have changed since the installation.

I could run a diff between the commit at the time of the installation of the extension and now, but this would show me all changed files. I want to only see the files that are in the extension itself (I have the original source if neccessary).

what is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: when you installed an extension you has been commit these changes?

Comment: if you know files extension you can try this solution:               git diff -- '*.<extension>'

Comment: yes, the installation of the extension has been committed.

"extension" here is not a file extension. it's a bunch of files that are scattered all over the source tree.